# Prevent wifi scan throttling on Android 9 (Pie) with NETWORK_SETTINGS permission

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-9.0-pie

As some have [noted](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/79906367?pli=1), Android 9 (Pie) severely restricts wifi scans, thus crippling any apps that do wifi logging or wifi-based location lookups with a frequency similar to a GPS.

As described in the ticket linked above:

- Each foreground app is restricted to 4 scans every 2 minutes
- All background apps combined are restricted to one scan every 30 minutes
- Apps holding `android.Manifest.permission.NETWORK_SETTINGS` permission are exempted from scan throttling (cf. [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#EXTRA_RESULTS_UPDATED))

However, I don’t find `android.Manifest.permission.NETWORK_SETTINGS` described anywhere in the docs (I would expect it to be documented at [android.manifest.permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission)).

If I simply declare
    
in the manifest, the app builds OK, installs OK but I don’t see any extra permissions (even when I choose to show all), at least on Oreo (unfortunately I don’t have a Pie device to test on yet).

Is `android.Manifest.permission.NETWORK_SETTINGS` a regular permission that’s available to regular user (i.e. non-system) apps?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately that's a `signature` level permission reserved only for system applications:

```
<!-- Allows Settings and SystemUI to call methods in Networking services
     <p>Not for use by third-party or privileged applications.
     @hide This should only be used by Settings and SystemUI.
-->
<permission android:name="android.permission.NETWORK_SETTINGS"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Source: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Shame. Am I correct in assuming that `signature` means the signature key of the app must match that of the OS, so that installable apps could still obtain this permission if they are obtained from the OS vendor and signed with the same key, while on the other hand apps which are part of the system image can’t if they are signed with a different key than the OS?

Comment: So is there any way we can prevent wifi-throttling in Android Pie then? At least in local development environment?

Answer (score 2):

[It is rumoured](https://www.androidpolice.com/2019/01/27/background-location-access-for-third-party-apps-might-return-in-android-q/) that Android Q will have a new permission android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION that allows background scanning. The docs say it "Allows an app to access location in the background." The [protection level is "dangerous"](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) rather than "signature".

Comment: Interesting. The sources mention only location, though—any information if that is going to affect wifi scans specifically?

Comment: I don't think its been confirmed. It might only apply to GPS position.